# Where is my desktop background?

Tags: unity, desktop-background, appearance

After upgrading my Ubuntu laptop from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 I "lost" the background wallpaper.

The background is completely black. It stays the same regardless of the wallpaper I select.

It switches between these two:

[image: my desktop]
[image: my deskto with lightdm screen in background]

However I can see the wallpaper that is set when I lock the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop background turn black after upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287571/desktop-background-turn-black-after-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04)