# Desktop shows a white or black background instead of wallpapers

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background

After the upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 my desktop background turns black after I try to set a image for that. How to fix it?

This is my desktop screen:
[image: My desktop screen after upgrade to 13.04]

Comment: The purge method in the following link helped me.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/204506/nautilus-stopped-working-after-update-to-3-6-1

Comment: Can you right-click on the desktop to change the background to something else?

Comment: I already do that but it not work.
I find the solution behind and it work>
thank for support

Comment: Switching to Adwaita (default) worked. Odd all other GTK themes are broken and cause the odd all white background.

Comment: **@Sripad:** The **purge** method relates to *Gnome3* and *Nautilus*. **Seems like a *Red Herring* (false trail) ..**

Comment: Solved for me, using *drastic method* from link in **@user152828**'s answer.

Comment: Possibly this bug:[Bug #1159430](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1159430)

Comment: I have the an issue with similar symptoms on Ubuntu 13.10 [1], but none of the fixes proposed here solved it. It seems the problem on Ubuntu 13.10 is of an entirely different nature. [1] http://askubuntu.com/questions/385594/wallpaper-suddenly-went-black-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I tried this and it worked!

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

update 2021 with ubuntu 21.10

if the above dosen't work you might need to follow this

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/shemgp/gnome-40/ubuntu/ hirsute main`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop --reinstall
```

Comment: This is Gnome specific, and may not apply for normal setup.

Comment: Well this one worked! but after this if set 'desktop icons' to off in Ubuntu tweak, will this error repeat? or now i can freely set them to off?

Comment: you can turn off desktop icon by ubuntu tweak.
I turn off desktop icons too and it worked for me.

Comment: worked perfect!!

Comment: This fix does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Has the same problem here with gnome+ubuntu desktop. This fixed it immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Worked for 14.10 as well.

Comment: Works for me on 15.10.

Comment: Worked for me first in 16.04, but after a few restarts an error came `low graphics mode` and after i rebooted the background became white instead of black

Comment: Oh man ! It works like a charm !

Comment: didn't worked for 16.04

Answer (score 18):

Having the same problem.

A workaround I've found through random clicking is to turn on desktop icons.

This can be done with dconf-editor or ubuntu-tweak-tool. The second is the easiest:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak-tool
```

Then launch it from the menu.

Under System/Desktop Icons you'll find a toggle to enable icons on the desktop. Switch this on, and suddenly -- wallpaper! This stays there if you turn off desktop icons but disappears again on login.

I've just allowed desktop icons to stay enabled, but simply any from my desktop.

Comment: This works but why? Is it a bug for Unit Tweak Tool?

Comment: I believe it is a bug in Nautilus (the file manager), but I haven't been able to find a launchpad bug yet.

Comment: Couldn't find ubuntu-tweak-tool. I found unity-tweak-tool. Is that what you meant? It has the System/Desktop Icons tab, but switching it on (and off) didn't bring the wallpaper back.-(

Comment: Perhaps: **Unity Tweak Tool**  *Use with caution, still bug fiklled.*

Comment: using 13.04, only that answer worked for me. this should be the accepted answer. way to go!

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 9):

Right click isn't working for me either...cause the desktop is not handled by file manager now.

Try doing reset of dconf/`unity --reset`... but it makes lose all your settings...I've found one link:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/217369

Maybe this can help.

---

**SOME DETAILS:** *(from link, with minor edit for clarity)*

> *.. you can reset the settings from terminal. (CTRL+ALT+T).*

or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

> *"You will lose all of your settings .. even the background. .. apply the commands below one at time."*

Check your spelling, and/or *print* this first.

> ```
> gconftool --shutdown
>
> sudo killall -r -I gconf
> sudo killall -r -I dconf
>
> rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*
> ```
>
> Restart PC
>
> ```
> sudo shutdown -r now
> ```

Comment: Confirm this worked for **13.04**; just updated today from 12.04/12.10.

Comment: Since none of the other fixes presented here work on 13.10 I decided to give this one a try. It neither brings the background back on 13.10, and now I'll have to go through the pain of reconfiguring. Note that one of the things this fix does is to activate data collection by Canonical and Amazon.

Comment: Working, but I had to activate that:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true

Answer (score 6):

Quick fix - install "Gnome Tweak Tool" and in the Desktop section uncheck "Have file manager handle the desktop."

Comment: I have already tried disabling the file manager from handling the desktop and once i do that, I have no desktop, the whole setup just glitches out. My whole system constantly freezes until i re enable the file manager handling the desktop. And no rebooting does not help.

Comment: This is Gnome specific, and may not apply for normal setup.

Comment: This fix does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 4):

Un-tick "Have file manager handle the desktop" in Gnome Tweak Tool and your wallpaper should show up again.

Comment: This worked for me and was the quickest and simplest solution.

Comment: This fix does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 3):

No need to turn off "Have file manager handle the desktop" or reinstall anything.

Just change theme to default, that will work until this is fixed. Ergo, change GTK theme to Adwaita (using a tool like Gnome Tweak Tool).

Comment: This has no effect on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

I got my desktop with these steps

1. Login to Ubuntu with unity interface
2. kill gnome-session using terminal (killall -e gnome-session). (Looks like Gnome 3 overrides Unity.)
3. Step 2 will kill the shell.
4. login to gnome (u might get a white desktop at this point) and use gnome-tweak tool to turn off "Have file manager handle the desktop". (Tweak Tool > Desktop> Have file manager handle the desktop-OFF).
5. login back to Unity.

I got my desktop screen back with those steps

Comment: Didnt work for me :(

Comment: This is Gnome specific, and may not apply for normal setup.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the desktop and untick "show desktop icons" or "show icons" does that fix the wallpaper display issue? If so, go through Gconf editor to the gnome desktop settings, set draw desktop to off, reboot, set it to on, reboot, and it should work. I had the same issue

Comment: None of those options show up if you right click on the Desktop on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purge the PPA from GNOME3. This is probably the issue here an update could cause the problem from this PPA.

I had similar issues for 13.04 and purging this solved it.

Open terminal & follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: yes, this is the solution that worked for me. there is a bug using gnome 3.8 with unity

Comment: This is Gnome specific, and may not apply for normal setup. I don't even have that PPA loaded.

Comment: This fix does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. To resolve I removed the Nautilus (with purge to remove the configuration files), and then installed again. Problems arose broken packages, but it was enough to remove them all and install again also. I ended the session and everything was normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed Ubuntu-Gnome 13.10. For me, in order to use a background, I can not use the settings as they just leave me a white screen. Instead, I choose any screen I want to use with Firefox. I right click on the image and choose to use as background. This actually works with the options for stretch, fit, tile, etc.

Comment: This fix does not work on Ubuntu 13.10.