# No wallpaper after update

Tags: updates, 13.04, desktop-background

I updated the system from the software updater and it required restart , after the laptop restarting no wallpaper on the desktop even if i changed it like below
[image]

any help ??

Comment: Maybe [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287571/desktop-shows-a-white-or-black-background-instead-of-wallpapers)

Comment: What graphics (on your laptop)? eg. *Intel B43, Nvidia, etc.*