# Ubuntu default problem

Tags: keyboard-layout, desktop-background

I am currently in a very difficult problem right now please please help me out.
I wanted to add the "knotes" as the default startup app in my **ubuntu 12.04** so I added it in startup application menu, while adding I saw other apps which I thought were not useful so **I removed those apps** (This seems to be a very big mistake)

And now I am unable to **change the wallpaper**(I tried every possible option), Ubuntu keeps asking me about **12.10 upgrade** even if I say "Don't Upgrade" and the worst problem is my **keyboard layout is automatically selected to "English(UK)**" which I am unable to change Because whatever layout I select it gets automatically changed to "English(UK)".I can't even type a single sentence properly(coz all keys are changed).
I am in very serious trouble right now as I can not reinstall whole ubuntu now

Please Please help me guys!

output of:
**ls /etc/xdg/autostart**

```
at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop
bluetooth-applet.desktop
bluetooth-applet-unity.desktop
deja-dup-monitor.desktop
gdu-notification-daemon.desktop
gnome-fallback-mount-helper.desktop
gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop
gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop
gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop
gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
gnome-screensaver.desktop
gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
gnome-sound-applet.desktop
gnome-user-share.desktop
gsettings-data-convert.desktop
gwibber.desktop
jockey-gtk.desktop
jockey-kde.desktop
nautilus-autostart.desktop
nm-applet.desktop
onboard-autostart.desktop
orca-autostart.desktop
polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
print-applet.desktop
pulseaudio.desktop
pulseaudio-kde.desktop
synaptiks_init_config.desktop
telepathy-indicator.desktop
ubuntuone-launch.desktop
update-notifier.desktop
user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
vino-server.desktop
zeitgeist-datahub.desktop
```

Comment: So, you've "hacked" the system, ha ? Because the startup applications are hidden by default. No startup applications showed by default in Ubuntu. Open a terminal and give the results of this command `ls /etc/xdg/autostart` . Edit your question and add the results.

Comment: I haven't done this(Hacking and all...) deliberately but I am sure that I messed up with something...Anyway added output in the question itself

Comment: Startup applications are all there. You haven't remove any of them, because you said: "...I added it in startup application menu, while adding I saw other apps which I thought were not useful so I removed those apps" . Do you want to reset your system in primary settings ? See the 2nd answer (counting from above to bottom) [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287571/desktop-shows-a-white-or-black-background-instead-of-wallpapers)

Comment: Even my shortcuts whcih I added to side pane are also gone..also sound is working but on toolbar it shows something wicked widget..I tried checking file system and remounting it from recovery mode it solved the problem for keyboard(may be because I did reconfiguration) but other things are still having problems..Anyway if I reset settings then will I loose any data or will it remove any apps?

Comment: Ha! One more problem: now unable to open software centre(nothing happens after clicking the icon) and when I say "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak-tool" it says unable to locate package

Comment: No, you will not lose any data or/and apps. Only your settings. Ubuntu will become like day one (when you first installed it).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, did u maybe boot in read mode only ?

1. Shutdown the computer
2. Boot into Recovery Mode --After BIOS load, hold down Shift key to
   access the grub menu --Once in grub menu, select the entry ending in
   "(recovery mode)"
3. From the next menu selected option to enter Root Session
4. At the root session, execute command `mount -o remount,rw /` to
   remount the filesystem as read-write

for keyboard layout try this :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```