# Wallpaper suddenly went black on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, desktop-background

This one is really strange. Two days ago the wallpaper on Ubuntu 13.10 simply went black. I have repeatedly tried to change it in the Appearance menu back to an image, or one of the default wallpapers, but it remains persistently black. I have no clue of what to do. Thanks.

**Update I**: some things I have tried that did not work:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`
- Purging the gnome3 PPA
- Setting the wallpaper with Firefox

I have desktop icons, thus I don't think that could be a cause.

**Update II**: I captured [a video of this strange desktop behaviour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTaDJOaupQI).

**Update III**: other fixes that are reported to work on Ubuntu 13.04, but are unsuccessful on Ubuntu 13.10:

- [Resetting configurations](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/217369)
- Unticking the "show desktop icons" option (it doesn't exist in Ubuntu 13.10)
- Unticking "Have file manager handle the desktop" in Gnome Tweak Tool
- Changing the GTK theme to Adwaita

**Update IV**: Logging in to a Gnome Flashback session I get the same behaviour with the wallpaper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop shows a white or black background instead of wallpapers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287571/desktop-shows-a-white-or-black-background-instead-of-wallpapers)

Comment: That's on Ubuntu 13.04, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: So far the fixes for 13.04 have proven unsuccessful, please do not close this question.

Comment: In the video you posted I never see the wallpaper getting set, let alone suddenly going blank. Also you seem to have a lot of lag while minimizing windows. Are you having your display drivers installed properly(in case you have proprietary graphics cards)?

Comment: The video starts precisely with the wallpaper getting set, with the background remaining black. I do not have any proprietary drivers installed and do not have any display issues.

Comment: Did you install different desktop environment such as mint?

Comment: No, I only have Unity and Gnome Flashback.

Comment: Actually, running `sudo aptitude search desktop`, I found out that Cinnamon was installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [hint by kenn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385594/wallpaper-suddenly-went-black-on-ubuntu-13-10#comment516070_385594), I verified that my problems are caused by Cinnamon. I never installed it myself, but I use Nemo. The [package catalogue](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/nemo) does not list any Cinnamon packages as dependencies for Nemo, but somehow it got fully installed. The solution to bring the wallpaper back to functioning order is thus:

```
sudo apt-get remove cinnamon*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And afterwards log out and log back in.

Weird thing is: this actually removed Nemo and now I don't have a graphical file manager.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Nemo is set to 'NOT handle the desktop'.

Run this command: `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can see in the answer below a symbol with a green tick, this means the answer has been accepted as a solution to  the question. Please [take a site tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) for more details.

Comment: There can be multiple answers, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

and

```
     sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak-tool
```

try this hope will work

Comment: I already tried the first solution (please read the question). The package you suggest is not available from the official repos for 13.10, would you suggest a PPA? What am I then supposed to do with that tool?

Comment: kindly update your machine first

Comment: Artemis, how will an update register a PPA?

Comment: Ok, so I found the [tualatrix](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/downloads/) PPA and installed the tool from there. This tool has a menu called *Love Wallpaper HD* that allows the selection of a wallpaper from the web. If you are referring to this, it has no impact on my desktop wallpaper.

Comment: Actually this helped me escape the black desktop on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you with the black desktop. I'm running unity on ubuntu 13.10 with cinnamon and nemo installed. I've found that if I log out of unity to the login screen the desktop background appears. I wait about 15 secs and then log back into unity and then the desktop background works as normal.

Obviously this is not the ideal solution but it does work for me anyway, hope it works  for you!

Comment: I can confirm the above answer from Picard (setting gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false) worked for me. I also set:-

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true

The Unity desktop background now works as normal and I can still use nemo.