# How to revert unity and remove gnome desktop?

Tags: unity, gnome, reset

I just installed gnome in Ubuntu 13.10 following this article at [www.omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/upgrade-gnome-3-10-ubuntu-13-10)

After reboot , weird things started happening :

- Gnome desktop always crashes (hang and unusable)
- no mouse cursor in unity and login window
- Mouse scrool act opposite
- wallpaper is now gone ! Even applying new pic as wallpaper didn't solve
- horrible graphics

I am new to Ubuntu and now I don't know how to revert old unity and remove gnome !

How can I solve this?

Answer as simple as you can .

[image]

Comment: Try weather you can select Unity at loggin. Click on the [huge dot](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-S83BpRdAYgI/Tpd3Ao3E3BI/AAAAAAAABzM/gsg_BiiGodM/s1600/ubuntu11.10-lightdm-login-screen.png) or the ubuntu logo in front of your username. ( In the screen you enter password at login). It will list if it is still available. see.

Comment: i m able to login in unity but unity seems broken ! same problem arises again ! no cursor , dark wallpaper , and seems like hang program in windows xp ! ;(

Comment: Follow the steps in the artcle to remove that ppa and remove gnome. copy down the steps in a paper. If you can open the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T you can do it. Otherwise Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and get the command prompt.

Comment: I have the same problem with my background [1], but I don't have GNome installed. You might be dealing with something more serious. [1] http://askubuntu.com/questions/385594/wallpaper-suddenly-went-black-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 8):

If GUI is troubling you, login through CLI(Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Check if **`ppa-purge`** package is installed or not.

Run

```
dpkg -l | grep ppa-purge
```

If it returns the value, `ppa-purge` is installed. If not, install it as follows;

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

After that run the following commands;

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Reboot system and login through Unity.

Answer (score 0):

- CTRL+ALT+F1 or Open Terminal
- sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-shell -y
- Restart PC

okay, Try using this  [[link]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244654/remove-ubuntu-gnome-desktop)

**You must have read the comments on that site before installing man

Comment: nth happens ! here's what i got 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

To revert back to Unity I checked the APT log (`/var/log/apt/term.log`) to see what other packages were installed alongside `gnome-shell` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and purged those:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libytnef0 libevolution evolution-common evolution gnome-themes-standard-data gnome-themes-standard libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libcolord-gtk1 libgdm1 libgrilo-0.2-1 libimdi0 libmediaart-1.0-0 libpst4 libxcb-xf86dri0 libxcb-xv0 libicc2 libmusicbrainz5-0 libnss-myhostname python-cloudfiles argyll dconf-editor deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles python-boto deja-dup-backend-s3 evolution-plugins fonts-cantarell gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 mutter-common libmutter0c gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gnome-icon-theme-full libmozjs-24-0 libgjs0e gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gjs gnome-session gnome-shell-common gnome-shell mutter gdm gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 libiptcdata0 libtracker-sparql-0.16-0 libtracker-extract-0.16-0 libtracker-miner-0.16-0 gir1.2-tracker-0.16 libzapojit-0.0-0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-backgrounds gnome-color-manager tracker libgupnp-av-1.0-2 grilo-plugins-0.2 gnome-online-miners gnome-documents gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gtk2-engines-pixbuf gvfs-backends-goa libgsf-1-common libgsf-1-114 libnetaddr-ip-perl libmail-spf-perl libreoffice-style-tango mcp-account-manager-goa plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text re2c spamassassin sa-compile spamc tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils ubuntu-gnome-default-settings gnome-sushi itstool xsltproc yelp-tools zsync ubuntu-gnome-desktop ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-trusty ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers xserver-xephyr evolution-indicator archives/unoconv
```

then to be sure:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop lightdm
```

This worked great for me.