# How to recover Ubuntu from bad Gnome remove?

Tags: unity, gnome, startup

Recently installed gnome-shell over Ubuntu, but it wasn't really as I rembered it so tried to go back. Followed a set of recommended steps here on AskUbuntu, mainly from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396280/how-to-revert-unity-and-remove-gnome-desktop) and followed the last answer that can be summoned as following:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-*
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

In the install ubuntu-dekstop step Ubuntu crashed and when rebooted Ubuntu now fails to start a session. Log in screen can be reached, but the graphics looks a bit odd. When trying to log in the only message I get is simply "Failed to start session".

So I figured that the steps I followed may have been to aggressive and that Ubuntu took a serious hit when I tried to remove GNOME and install ubuntu-desktop again. My question is how I can recover this? Is their a way to reach terminal in the start up session so I can finish the supposed unfinished ubuntu-desktop installation? Or is their another way?

Edit: I of course got the answer how to reach terminal from Login screen by googling, but the problem still exist. How to recover from this mess?

Comment: Your problem may be very similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/446651/apt-get-remove-purge-wine-removed-everything and I'm afraid I do not know of a graceful way to recover from this.

Comment: It is similar although I never used purge in the commands I recounted here. In earlier steps though, which where unsuccessful of removing Gnome, I used ppa-purge and purge to remove gmd. Graphics for Gnome did'nt go away this way and that's why I used `sudo apt-get remove gnome-*` from the begining.

Comment: My understanding (poor, I admit) is that apt-get uses regex for matching the patterns, and there may be many packages with `gnome` in the name...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Exactly, figured as much too when the command prompt went bananas and started to delete packages not releted to the gnome-shell. Banans is maybe the wrong word for this, because I'm the one to blame for this.

Comment: If you can still get to terminal mode, then you could backup your important files...

Comment: See my own answer to the question. Files are intact actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured some bits out but still a lot of damage seems to been done. I went to terminal from the Login screen and remade my earlier step by typing in

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This is a part answer for my earlier question. As pointed out in comments earlier the command I used removed every package with `gnome` in the name. A lot of package seems not to have been reinstalled when using `install ubuntu-desktop`. For starters - both Chromium and Mozilla seems to be missing.

So any one that have any idea how to reinstall this packages with a single command? Or do I need to retrace my steps to find every removed package and install them by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to retry the installation of packages.

Comment: This only gave me the answer that there where nothing to install.