# Unable to restart Nautilus (required by Dropbox)

Tags: nautilus, dropbox, glib

Every time I log in Dropbox opens up the screen informing me that Nautilus needs to be restarted.

[image: Dropbox "Nautilus Restart Requried"]

Clicking the restart button does nothing though.

If I enter terminal and run `nautilus -q` it returns the following errors:

```
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0

(nautilus:8933): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 310 was not found when attempting to remove it
(nautilus:8933): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 311 was not found when attempting to remove it
(nautilus:8933): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 312 was not found when attempting to remove it`
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve these errors so that I can restart nautilus correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try**

`sudo nautilus -q`

or install a newer Nautilus for **14.04/13.10** from [here](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-nautilus-3-12-2-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/)

EDIT: What I forgot, after installing Nautilus 3.12, you will have to reboot -> `sudo reboot`

Report back if it worked ;)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned I have also tried running `sudo nautilus -q`. I'll try updating nautilus and seeing whether I still get the message / am unable to restart after rebooting.

Comment: I just started getting this error. How did you end up resolving this problem? Did the nautilus update work?

Comment: I had the same issue, tried following the instruction in the link (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install nautilus, sudo apt) but after rebooting the "Nautilus restart required" box still pops up seconds after logging in and also my display settings have changed - background tabs in browser have greyed out text that is impossible to read, the "nautilus restart required" box didn't have a box where it said "restart nautilus", just the words...very annoying. Does anyone know a way to fix this or at least undo what the last advice did?

Answer (score 2):

I hope your problem has been resolved, if not this may help. I was also facing the same problem and this helped me.

Download the `.deb` file of Dropbox from [here on the dropbox.com site](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx).

Then after download, right click and select Open with software install.

Then install it.

[image: software center]

Start drop box and you will get little dropbox icon on top right.

[Reference](https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/install-dropbox-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after having installed Ubuntu 16.04 und Dropbox, nothing else. I have no idea which Nautilus comes with Ubuntu, but as it is the newest Ubuntu, I assume, it's also the newest Nautilus. So I did not do any update on Nautilus, but only ran

```
sudo reboot.
```

After a PC Restart the **Nautilus Restart Required** window showed up again, but now I was able to close it from the <kbd>Close</kbd> button. From then on, the window never showed up again.