# Unable to downgrade GNOME from 3.20 to 3.18

Tags: apt, gnome, 16.04, ppa

I'd like to downgrade GNOME because 3.20 on my Ubuntu 16.04 is a mess. There are countless sources on the Internet (including [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/396291/394896)) saying how to do this, and it's always:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

(optionally also `sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next`)

However, I'm getting nowhere with this.

**`$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`:**

```
Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

**`$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`:**

```
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/cardapio-ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cardapio-team/unstable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

GNOME stays the same version after reboot. Excuse me if this is just a matter of googling some part of the output, I have tried to search also for something general concerning `ppa-purge` failing. I'm a below-average end user. I'll be happy to provide more info.

---

As requested, [`$ sudo apt-get update` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/20296909/), and `$ sudo apt-get upgrade` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```