# Screen refresh problem on Unity over Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, rhythmbox, .desktop, 15.10

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10 with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Everything worked fine. But when I tried to change the desktop background unity crashed. I restarted the computer and tried to change the desktop background again but the background didn't change.

Now when I try to move any windows, the dragged window leaves trail behind. This happens only when the window are dragged on desktop background. 
[image]

But when I drag windows over other (maximized) windows there is no such problem.

What might have happened and how can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I have realized that this problem occurs only when rhythmbox is running. If I kill rhythmbox process using system monitor or not start it all then the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm not running rhythmbox. Any word on the cause? http://i.imgur.com/MnmNzFa.jpg

Comment: I am not certain which specific rhythmbox component caused this problem, but I opened up Synaptic Package Manager and completely removed all the rhythmbox related packages and reinstalled. That did for me. Remember the last package you changed before getting this problem, remove that package and see if it works.

Comment: Removed rhythmbox via the Software Center. Restarted. No dice. Reinstalled rhythmbox. Restarted. Still have the issue. :/

Comment: Of note: I hadn't installed any packages prior to this. I had just upgraded to 15.10. I also observe that the monitor going to sleep and restarting "fixes" it.

Comment: Was Nemo part of the rhythmbox packages you removed and reinstalled? I removed Nemo and the refresh issue stopped. Still haven't figured out how to get my desktop to display an image, however.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10 via update manager. 
[image: sample image]

I did not have rhythmbox running. I removed and reinstalled it, as well as all dependent packages, via the software center; those did nothing.

Scrolling through the system monitor, I noticed that [Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemo_(file_manager)) was running. I killed it and the desktop refresh problem immediately stopped. I was, however, left with a black desktop background that did not display my wallpaper. The instructions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/287573/379677) answer worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

I'm not sure what the underlying cause of these problems is, but I hope this answer will at least help people work around it.

Comment: Is there a corresponding value for Ubuntu-MATE? (The key mentioned already exists and is set to `true` on my Ubuntu-MATE 16.04)