# Why does the removal of this nautilus security threat cause the desktop background to go black?

Tags: nautilus, security

I noticed some files `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/` files.  Those files are not text, they are some binary proprietary format.  However, using a binary viewer (GHex) I could view some plain ascii strings in those files.  I noticed that these strings contained sensitive information such as the locations of password key files.

In order to turn off this sensitive information collection "feature" I took the following steps:

1. Installed Thunar (an alternative file system broswer)
2. Disabled `/use/bin/nautilus` by removing executing permission (`chmod -x /use/bin/nautilus`)
3. deleting the files ~`/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*`

After rebooting I could confirm that (at least not over the course of a single day) the sensitive information was no longer being recorded in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*`.

However, an unfortunate side effect of disabling nautilus is that the desktop background picture ceases to function and the desktop background remains black.  Returning the execution permissions on `/usr/bin/nautilus` results in a return of the desktop background (but also in a return of the unwanted accumulation of sensitive information).

My question is:

- **Why does the background function depend upon nautilus** (considering that file-browsing and desktop background are not naturally related)?

not to mention

- **How can I make background work again without enabling nautilus?**

edit:  I had previously noticed a similar security problem with the data files accumulated under the `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` folder.  I also found that using the clear zeitgeist history function didn't actually remove the sensitive information from the data files under the `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` folder.   I addressed that problem by removing the execute permissions from the zeitgeist service binaries "zeitgeist-*".      Perhaps this is related to the problem, e.g., maybe the sensitive information is written to `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/...` because it could not be written to `~/.local/share/zeitgeist/...` ?

Comment: My guess would be that it is connected to desktop background...

Comment: Desktops show the files in your desktop folder as icons and you can open them, change their metadata, and create new ones. So they're *usually* managed by file browsers. [This *should* be an answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281)...but I think your last question is the main one. Can you **[edit]** to add: Did you just install `thunar` or did you do more to configure it? Does your desktop work at all? Does it show files in your `Desktop` folder? Does a right-click do anything? If so, can you show a screenshot of that? Are you using Unity? GNOME Shell? What's the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: @Eliah Kagan - You answered the question about why they are related.  I took the liberty to quote your comment and make it the answer

Comment: @CraigHicks Thanks--looks good! Answer upvoted. I would've thought the method you used would still require Nautilus to be able to run--it's good to know it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Eliah Kagan for the comment answering the question on why nautilus is related to background function:

- *"Desktops shows the desktop folder's entries as icons and you can open them, change their metadata, and create new ones. So they're usually managed by file browsers."*

I found a solution to getting the background to work again from 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/287573/723997).  That solution is

- `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`