# No wallpaper Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: desktop-background

After upgrading my system (ubuntu 13.04 64bit) and restart the computer, my desktop wallpaper ran out, only appears a white background, someone could help me with this?

Comment: Is it still white if you try to change the wallpaper?

Comment: The same problem is here → http://askubuntu.com/questions/282765/where-is-my-desktop-background

Comment: yes, and it did not work

Comment: Solved for me, from link / answer at top.